# it is possible to monkeypatch a local variable introduced in a function body?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

In [py.test monkeypatching/mocking documentation](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/monkeypatch.html) this is not mentioned, but it is possible to monkeypatch a local variable introduced in a function body?

my experiment:

```
def my_method():
    my_var = 'foo'
    return my_var[:2]
```

test is:

```
def test_my_method(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr(my_module.MyClass.my_method.my_var, lambda: 'bar')
    assert my_method() == 'ba'
```

> AttributeError: 'function' object at MyClass.my_method has no
>   attribute 'my_var'

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Can you post some minimal code with which you tried the monkeypatching, as well as a boiled down version of the code you want to apply it to? (See [mcve].) Also, what are you trying to achieve by the monkey-patching? Maybe there's a better way for your context.

Comment: You have [tag:py.test] in your question's tags. Are you trying to stub/mock/fake/double something for testing purposes?

Comment: Variable defined in local scope of method is not equivalent to an attribute of the method. Please show us [MCVE].

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not possible as the variable does not exist ahead of time and py.test cannot hook into the creation of a local variable as far as i know.

Answer (score 5):

With a little care, it would be possible to patch the consts in the function code object using [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html).

```
import ctypes
from contextlib import contextmanager

def tuple_setitem(tup, index, item):
    obj = ctypes.py_object(tup)
    item = ctypes.py_object(item)
    ref_count = ctypes.c_long.from_address(id(tup))
    original_count = ref_count.value
    if original_count != 1:
        ref_count.value = 1
    ctypes.pythonapi.Py_IncRef(item)
    ctypes.pythonapi.PyTuple_SetItem(obj, ctypes.c_ssize_t(index), item)
    ref_count.value = original_count

@contextmanager
def patch_tuple_item(tup, index, item):
    old = tup[index]
    try:
        tuple_setitem(tup, index, item)
        yield
    finally:
        tuple_setitem(tup, index, old)
```

Demo:

```
>>> def my_method():
...     my_var = "foo"
...     return my_var[:2]
...
>>> consts = my_method.__code__.co_consts
>>> consts
(None, 'foo', 2)
>>> with patch_tuple_item(consts, index=1, item="bar"):
...     print(my_method())
...
ba
>>> print(my_method())
fo
```